# Clarification for the proof of Taylor's remainder theorem

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, taylor-expansion

I am confused by the final part of the following proof for the Taylor's remainder theorem. In particular to me it does not seem that $F(x) = F(x_0)$, since by definition $F(x) = 0$, and $F(x_0) = f(x)$. In any case here is the proof.

> Suppose $f\in \mathcal{C}^{n+1}[[a, b]]$ with $x_0 \in (a, b)$. Let
> $R$ be defined by the equation $f(x) =
> > \left(\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{f^{(i)}(x)}{i!}(x - x_0)^i\right) +
> > \frac{R}{(n+1)!}(x - x_0)^{n+1}$. Furthermore define $F(\xi) =
> > \left(\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{f^{(i)}(x)}{i!}(x - \xi)^i\right) +
> > \frac{R}{(n+1)!}(x - \xi)^{n+1}$ so that $F'(\xi) = f'(\xi) +
> > \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{f^{(i+1)}(\xi)}{i!}(x - \xi)^i -
> > \frac{f^{(i)}(\xi)}{(i - 1)!}(x - \xi)^{i - 1}\right) - \frac{R}{n!}(x
> > - \xi)^{n} = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{n!}(x - \xi)^n - \frac{R}{n!}(x - \xi)^n = \frac{(x - \xi)^n}{n!}(f^{(n+1)}(\xi) - R)$.
>
> Then **clearly** $F(x_0) = F(x) = f(x)$, so that by Rolle's theorem
> there exists a point $\xi$ between $x$ and $x_0$ such that $F'(\xi) =
> > 0 \Longleftrightarrow R = f^{(n+1)}(\xi)$.

In order to use the Rolle's theorem we need that $F(x) = F(x_0)$. But like I said above, isn't $F(x) = 0$ by definition and $F(x_0) = f(x)$, so that unless $f(x) = 0$ we do not have the necessary conditions for Rolle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the definition  $F(\xi) =
 \sum_{i=0}^n\frac{f^{(i)}(x)}{i!}(x - \xi)^i$ the starting term corresponding to $i=0$ is interpreted as $f(x)$ (and not $0$) even when $\xi=x$.

Comment: Ah I see. The exponentiation takes precedence over the subtraction.